# Splitting an English sentence into more lines

Tags: grammaticality

I am wondering if there is a rule for splitting a sentence in English into more lines. For example, I would like to get Tolkien's quote engraved on a tag (necklace).

> All we have to decide is what to do with the time that is given us.

But because the size of the tag, it won't be in one line, so that's why I am asking. In my native language for example you can't write preposition at the end of the line and the word on the next line if you read it "together", with one breath.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for opinions about formatting in  – essentially  – titles.

Answer (score 0):

In English writing you can break a line at
any space.

Even if the last word of the line is a two-letter preposition, or a
one-letter article.

Generally I try not to break after a one-letter initial.
For example: *J.

R. R. Tolkien* looks bad, I think.